# Selenide test in Jenkins:

Tags: jenkins, xvfb, selenide

i have tests written in Selenide.
On localhost Jenkins - they run successfully, but if i want put them on my company Jenkins - problems starts

My first attemp, without Xvfb:
Logs:

```html
[31mFailed scenarios:[0m
[31msrc/test/resources/features/Login.feature:6 [0m# Scenario: Login to programs with invalid credentials
[31msrc/test/resources/features/Login.feature:10 [0m# Scenario: Login to programs with valid credentials

2 Scenarios ([31m2 failed[0m)
6 Steps ([31m2 failed[0m, [36m4 skipped[0m)
0m3.089s

java.lang.IllegalStateException: No webdriver is bound to current thread: 1. You need to call open(url) first.
```

I dont know why, on local jenkins there's no error like You need to call open(url) first.

Second attemp, i read that xvfb is requied

configuration of xvfb in jenkins:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGn5f.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXCNb.png

Logs:

```html
Xvfb starting$ Xvfb :3 -screen 0 1024x758x16 -fbdir /var/lib/jenkins/xvfb-8-..fbdir5500835804021266071
ERROR: Failed to parse POMs
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "Xvfb": error=2, No such file or directory
 at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
 at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:249)
 at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:218)
 at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:929)
 at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:449)
 at org.jenkinsci.plugins.xvfb.Xvfb.launchXvfb(Xvfb.java:587)
 at org.jenkinsci.plugins.xvfb.Xvfb.setUp(Xvfb.java:697)
 at jenkins.tasks.SimpleBuildWrapper.setUp(SimpleBuildWrapper.java:146)
 at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.doRun(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:667)
 at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:504)
 at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1794)
 at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:543)
 at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
 at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
 at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
 at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:247)
 at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
 at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
 ... 13 more
Finished: FAILURE
```

Also if i uncheck on xvfb installation 'install automatically' and if i try set 'Directory in which to find Xvfb executable' to default /usr/bin - i see error 
Home path does not contain Xfvb executable: /usr/bin

Do You ever have problem like that with Jenkins?
What i should to do?
I can't use install automatically and should talk to Jenkins admin about path to xvfb executable?

Comment: Probably xvfb is missing and needs to be installed.

Comment: so check 'install automatically' in manage plugins it is not enough? We should install it manually and set path to installation? And without xfvb there's no chance to run tests?

Comment: Maybe the user under which jenkins is running hasn't the appropriate rights to install a package, so "install automatically" has failed. The executable not being available is a strong indicator that som4e installation has failed.

Comment: on https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Xvfb+Plugin I find: "Unfortunately there is no support for automatic installation of Xvfb"